# T0 space homeomorphism to the initial and final segment topology

Tags: general-topology

This is my attempted proof of the following problem from Topology Without Tears: Chapter 4.3. Exercise 7 (v). Please let me know if this is an acceptable proof, or if you can point out where it can be improved. Thank you.

*We are required to prove the following. Let ($X$,$\tau$) be a T$_0$-space which has no infinite T$_1$-subspaces. Then ($X$,$\tau$) has a subspace homeomorphic to ($\Bbb N$,$\tau_3$), where $\tau_3$ consists of $\Bbb N$, $\emptyset$, and all of the sets {1, 2, ...., n}, n $\in$ $\Bbb N$ or $\tau_3$ consists of $\Bbb N$, $\emptyset$, and all of the sets {n, n+1, ...}, n $\in$ $\Bbb N$.*

Since we're required to show $X$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N$, we assume $X$ is at least countably infinite. We choose a countably infinite subset $S$ $\subseteq$ $X$. Since $X$ is T$_0$, [$S$ is also T$_0$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/T0_Property_is_Hereditary):

Case 1:

$\forall$$x$$_1$, $x$$_2$ $\in$ $S$ : $x$$_1$ $\neq$ $x$$_2$, there exists some open $U_1$ $\subseteq$ $S$ : $x$$_1$ $\in$ $U_1$, $x$$_2$ $\notin$ $U_1$ (or visa versa, but we'll treat that in Case 2).

$S$ is infinite and $T_0$, so $\forall x$ must be in some $U$. However, $S$ is not $T_1$. If it was, we could separate $x$$_1$ $\in$ $U$ and $x$$_2$ $\in$ $V$, for two distinct open subsets $U$ and $V$. Since we can't, and as this is an infinite set, $x_2$ is in some $U_i$ but it cannot be in a distinct open set from $x_1$. This implies $x_1$ is in every open set as $x_2$ but not the converse.
We do this again with $x_2$ and $x_3$. There exists some open $U_2$ $\subseteq$ $S$ : $x_2$ $\in$ $U_2$, $x_3$ $\notin$ $U_2$.This implies $x_2$ is in every open set as $x_3$ but not the converse. 
We iterate this to $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ leaving us with the following:
$U_1$= {$x_1$} 
$U_2$= {$x_1$, $x_2$} 
$U_3$= {$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$} 
$U_n$= {$x_1$, ..., $x_n$} and so on.

Case 2:

$\forall$$x$$_1$, $x$$_2$ $\in$ $S$ : $x$$_1$ $\neq$ $x$$_2$, there exists some open $U_1$ $\subseteq$ $S$ : $x$$_1$ $\notin$ $U_1$, $x$$_2$ $\in$ $U_1$.
This is the reverse of Case 1: $x_2$ is in every open $U$ as $x_1$ but the opposite isn't true. $x_3$ is in every open $U$ as $x_2$ but the opposite isn't true. We iterate this leaving us with the following:
$U_1$= {$x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$} 
$U_2$= {$x_2, x_3, x_4, ...$} 
$U_3$= {$x_3, x_4, x_5, ...$} 
$U_n$= {$x_n, x_{n+1}, ...$} and so on.

The open sets in Case 1 are clearly homeomorphic to collection of sets {$1, 2, ...., n$}, $n \in$ $\Bbb N$ (known as the initial segment topology), and the open sets in Case 2 clearly homeomorphic to collection of sets {$n, n+1, ...$}, $n \in$ $\Bbb N$ (known as the final segment topology). This completes the proof. $\square$

Comment: Are you assuming $S$ is listed as $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$? If so, to show that it's enough to consider these two cases you probably need the infinite Ramsey thereom somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @183orbco3. I was not assuming $S$ is listed as such. Instead my approach was to choose arbitrary $x$ $\in$ $S$ and then assign them (map them) to $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$. We start with any two $x_i$ and $x_j$, realize one of them is in $U_1$, while the other isn't. These will be mapped to 1 and 2, respectively. Then $x_j$ and $x_k$, mapping to 2 and 3, and so on.

Comment: As stated, the claim is false, as $X = \{a,b\}, \tau = \{\emptyset, X, \{a\} \}$ is $T_0$ with no infinite $T_1$ subspaces. Your assumption that $X$ is infinite is necessary, and should be included in the theorem statement.